использую яндекс карты апи 2.1 , в нексте , создаю скрипт инициализирую карту , как поставить можно метку через клик по карте?
как в нексте поставить метки на яндекс карту через саму карту?
использую яндекс карты апи 2.1 , в нексте , создаю скрипт инициализирую карту , как поставить можно метку через клик по карте ?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Вы можете реализовать это путем прослушивания события click. Пример реализации с геокодированием клика представлен в нашей песочнице.
2024-10-28 19:34:39, mozzarella <>:

как в нексте поставить метки на яндекс карту через саму карту?
использую яндекс карты апи 2.1 , в нексте , создаю скрипт инициализирую карту , как поставить можно метку через клик по карте ?

